# Timers in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

What is the difference between timers and threadgroup (combination of "number of users" and "ramp up period")? With initial understanding both serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, hope its correct:

With Thread group i can set the delay between the successive users triggering the request and with Timers i can give the pause between the requests sent by same user.